# React Router 4 triggering full page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

React Router 4 is running on top of Rails and React, but following a `<Link />` element triggers a GET request in my server and a full page reload in my development environment.

Here are the current versions I'm running:

```
"@rails/webpacker": "^3.0.2",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
```

I'm using the foreman gem, which runs the rails server and webpack-dev-server on localhost:5000.

**What I've tried:**

- Adding `historyApiFallback` to my webpack-dev-server CLI
- Using either `<Link />` and `<NavLink />`
- Adding a trailing `/` to my links; `<Link path='/sign-in/' component={Register} />`
- Rendering *just* `<App />` at the highest level component, and adding `<BrowserRouter />` and all routing/switching to `<App />`
- I've tried using `exact path`, `strict path`, and just `path`

I'm curious if it's something with my webpack config... I can post that as well if necessary. It just seems like this is all set up right but something else funky is going on.

**What *is* working:**
- I can switch between components, even though my rails routes in `routes.rb` has a catch-all: `get '*path', to: 'pages#index'`

Here is my highest level component, **index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import Main from '../react/src/components/Main';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router>
            <Main />
        </Router>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
});
```

Here is **main.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import FormContainer from './FormContainer';

const Main = props => {
    return (
        <main>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/sign-in/" component={FormContainer} />
                <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Main;
```

An example of a component that is rendered, **Dashboard.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Dashboard = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Dashboard</h2>
            <Link to="/sign-in/">Sign In</Link>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

The empty controller responsible for my root page:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
end
```

Also my **routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#index"
  get '*path', to: 'pages#index'
end
```

I've gone through multiple tutorials and I'm fairly certain that this is structured correctly... I think I'm mainly looking for any hints as to what may be interfering with React Router, *outside* of the library, i.e. webpack, running on localhost, etc.

Comment: do you mean that clicking on any Link calls your server?  what do you see when you view source on the link?

Comment: Yeah - in the **Dashboard.js** example above, clicking on that *Sign In* link results in this activity on my server: `Started GET "/sign-in/" for...`, which then is processed by the controller. Response is OK at 200 for what it's worth, but I know react router should be all client-side.

Viewing the link source actually shows a regular anchor tag...
`<a aria-current="false" href="/sign-in/">Sign In</a>`

Comment: Are you using turbolinks in your Rails app? I'm asking because it's usually activated by default within Rails, and it could cause problems with the way links are handled (and thus screw up with your expected React Router behavior).

Comment: Nope, no turbolinks in this project.

Comment: it may be something unique around using '/' as the root path to serve the main html page that you use to initialize react, i've never tried that configuration.  maybe try serving the html from some concrete path like '/reactapp'?

Comment: Interesting idea, though no change - still activity on server + full page reload. I've moved my `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'index.js' %>` and `<div id='app'></div>` out into my `dashboard.html.erb` file, so now my root is _not_ react based, and `localhost:5000/home` directs to my react app. Did I understand that correctly?

It seems like my `<Link />` elements are behaving like regular anchor tags.

Comment: yeah that's what i was suggesting to serve the page from /home or something...  just brainstorming.  then you need to update your link to="/home/sign-in/" although i would drop the trailing slashes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by renaming a tag of `<main>` that my `application.html.erb`'s `<%= yield %>` tag was wrapped in... I don't quite understand why wrapping `<%= yield %>` in a tag specifically called `<main>` causes a page reload/disables client-side rendering, but in my case, it did!